# How do I 'break down' the array returned by my PDO query?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

So just as I began to get a good grasp on MySQL, I found out I should be learning about PDO. This is the (unfinished) code I have so far. I'd like to get it working before worrying about adding more password security. When I run the script, the printed message is "Array". How can I break this down and retrieve the data in the array?

```
try {
$db = new PDO($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
$statement = $db->prepare("select * from users where email = :name");
$statement->execute(array(':name' => $username));
$result = $statement->fetch();
echo $result;}

catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
```

Sorry if this is a silly question; I've been searching for a while, but can not find any good examples what match what I'm doing, and I learn better from examples than long, wordy descriptions (such as the PHP manual).

Comment: You'll want to retrieve it using a foreach for example. Lot's of tutorials out there. Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to review your PHP base first, these pages seems most appropriate:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Then, you can review again the code for Fetch and FetchAll at:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Note that arrays are the defacto standard when receiving data from any provider, should it be pdo, mysql, mysqli, pgsql, this is why i recommend you review the ARRAY type first, get a good grasp of it, then read PDO stuff again...

Comment: Also, i delocalized the mirror and used php.net by default, thx for mentionning Bono

Comment: I checked that out and managed to get it to work, thank you very much!